# run script on shutdown

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have the following script, how do I run it on shutdown in debian linux? (don't want to use GUI)

```
#!/bin/bash
vms=$(vmrun list | grep '/');
for vm in ${vms}
do
        echo 'suspending ' $vm
        vmrun suspend $vm soft
done
```

I tried adding it to /usr/local/bin with chmod +x permissions. Then I created symbolic links to rc0.d (shutdown) and rc6.d (reboot).

I then did update-rc.d shutdown_vms 0 6 .

When I do shutdown -r now, it switches to console mode to restart....at that point I can see a error message stating shutdown_vms has failed.

I this the proper way to install the shutdown script and why is it failing (where do I look in the logs?)

Edit:
I used the command update-rc.d -f shutdown_vms start 0 0 6 .

When I look at the start up list for rc0.d (shutdown), i see that both shutdown_vms, vmware, and gdm are all order of 0. I think if gdm fires before shutdown_vms, it will kill the vms. I think this is what's happening because when I log the number of vms running when the script executes, it logs 0.

Can I change the order of gdm/vmware to 1 so that shutdown_vms run first?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you should put it into a proper init-script as "stop" method. Your current script propably fails, because of an exit-code that is not equal to zero.

Apart from that you should enclose "$()" because your list of vms propably contains white space.

Test your script by `sh -x YOURSCRIPT stop`.

Comment: Running that outputs: + vmrun list
+ grep /
+ vms=
+ exit 0

Answer (score 2):

try adding: exit 0 under done.

so it looks like gdm does this during the shutdown process.
maybe a better way is that you let your vms script test if it really is necessary to go through the shutdown procedure. In that case it does nothing to shutdown a non-existent process. This non-existent process probably caused your error message.

Comment: Did that, didn't work. Is there anyway to know whether the script failed (some kind of log stored in var)? I ran the script manually and it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

Have you named the file starting with a 'K' in the /etc/rc[06].d directories?  If you don't then they will not be executed on shutdown.

Comment: I used update-rc.d -f shutdown_vms start 99 0 6 . which automaticaly puts K01shutdown_vms in /etc/rc0.d and /etc/rc6.d, it still doesn't work

Comment: I presume it works when you run it NOT in a shutdown scanario but NOT when in /etc/rc.d directories?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm...It would be nice if the failure output could be shown.  This would likely easily clearup some things.

One other thought, try putting in a PATH statement right after #!/bin/sh.

```
 #! /bin/sh
 PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:.....<anything else you need>
 export PATH
 .
 .   (rest of script)
 .
 exit 0
```

I'm not familiar with vmlist.